# Read multiple variables from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, io

I'm trying to split a string into different variables. Something like the opposite of `String.format()`. I want a particular *regex* to match and then that portion of the string should be assigned to a specific variable. Is that possible using `StringReader` or any other class?

Example my String is `5 13-DEC-2010 16:47 A Tach 220 380`
now it should be assigned to variables like:

1. `number = 5`
2. `date = 13-DEC-2010`
3. `time = 16:47`
4. `type = A Tach`
5. `num1 = 220`
6. `num2 = 380`

where all variables can be strings

Comment: I think he will have a problem with "A Tach". Otherwise, split is a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "5 13-DEC-2010 16:47 A Tach 220 380";
    String re = "(\\d+)\\s+(\\d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-\\d{4})\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s+([\\w\\s+]*)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
    String number=null,date=null,time=null,type=null,num1=null,num2=null;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        number = m.group(1);
        date = m.group(2);
        time = m.group(3);
        type = m.group(4);
        num1 = m.group(5);
        num2 = m.group(6);
    }
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(type);
    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println(num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = '5 13-DEC-2010 16:47 A Tach 220 380';
var re = /(\d+)\s+(\d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{4})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2})\s+([\w\s+]*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/
var m = s.match(re);
```

Answer (score 0):

Base from my past experience, there wasn't any builtin class that will do that. Just manually manipulate your data. Like split it (str.split("\s");), then stored in they respective variables. But the problem is the case "A Tach".

If you ask me I'll just replace the data seperator(in your case its a space) with a regex that will not occur in your string, something like ";=;" where your string will be transformed into
"5;=;13-DEC-2010;=;16:47;=;A Tach;=;220;=;380"
Then just split the data and parse it to their respective variable.